# calculate data miss rate in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

i need help for some exercises. I have to calculate the miss rate for data accesses in a code fragment in mips. I wanted to know which instructions I need to count, I know the load word (lw) accesses the data in memory and therefore I have to include it in the count. Should I also count the load address (la) and the store word (sw)? or these two instructions do not access the data in memory?

Answer (score 0):

`la` is an ALU pseudo-instruction to construct 32-bit constants, like `li`.  It assembles to one or both of `lui` / `ori`, and doesn't access memory.

`sw` is a store, so it writes memory but doesn't read it.  You should probably count stores if you want the total miss rate, rather than the load-miss rate.